# Ember strange behavior when two instances of same template used in multiple places in application

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Please take a look at this [JSBin1](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/milosoteguyi/1/edit). I am using the same template for both the `render` in the `index` template and manually rendered in the `renderTemplate` function of the `ColorsRoute`. Clicking the `More Colors` link does not render the list of colors I return in the `ColorsRoute` model hook. Now, if you change the `render 'colors-list model` to `render colors-list2 model`, as I have done [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cevagocekofu/1/edit), everything works as I would expect it to. The only difference between the two is that in JSBin1, I am only using the `colors-list` template, but in the second working example, I have one template for the `render` and an identical, differently named template for the `ColorsRoute`.

The code example, while trivial in the JSBin, is an exact extraction of something I am doing in a much larger application. This application has a bunch of widgets, which I represent by multiple named outlets in the same `templates`. I manually render into these outlets, as I do in the JSBin in the `ColorsRoute` `renderTemplate` hook. I do the manually rendering so that when certain events happen, I have `actions` defined on the `route` that will allow me to dynamically replace the contents of the `outlet` after making an ajax call to a REST API.

What is the explanation for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more related to the controller that's being created, not the template. And technically I'd say it shouldn't work on either, but it appears there's some route where if you don't define a controller, and that type of controller hasn't been created, create it, and use the current controller/model as the model backing it.

Really you should be providing a controller when using render if you're expecting it to have that controller as the backing controller.

```
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model){
    this.render();
    this.render('color-list', {
      outlet: "named", 
      into: 'colors',
      controller: controller
    });
  }
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cevagocekofu/3/edit